# The steering wheel turns left or right over small bumps

Tags: power-steering, abs, steering-wheel, cv-boot

I had my front rotors resurfaced, brake pads changed and some works done on steering wheel pump couple of weeks back.

Ever since then, I started noticing a few problems that weren't there before.

1. The car steer right and left even when over small bumps, potholes.
   Because of this I’m afraid to take it on highways.
2. There's this weird noise when I turn the steering in idle and running. But it's not there all the times.
3. The ABS light is on and sometimes the braking feels as if the pedal
       is making a contact with another metal.
4. I noticed a leakage in the axle boot, but it's gone all by itself
       now. So, I'm not really sure if the leakage is on the boot or from
       any parts above it. https://www.screencast.com/t/AxmkMGTxF

I feel that somehow all the issues are interconnected and would really appreciate your help in understanding the issue better.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Get it checked, the abs light should not be on - was it on before it went in for repair?

The axle boot needs to be checked - it may have stopped "leaking" as there is nothing left to leak out, so it will fail soon...

The "loose" steering may be one or more of the steering joints or suspension joints / bushes are worn - did you have these checked - if not you should do.

Comment: Thanks. ABS light started appearing only after the car went for repair. Planning to take the car to the same service station during the weekend. So, was just wondering if it's something to do with the brake pad change. Maybe there's an alignment issue during the brake pad change that the steering wheel now feels wobble, so need to have wheel alignment done?